# SQL Server Report Builder 3.0 exclude empty fields

Tags: sql-server-2008, reportbuilder

I am trying to generate reports with SQL Server Report Builder (my first time ever)

And I have a list with this fields: `name, order, weight, temp`

Sometimes the field `order` has no value. And I want to filter the rows where `order` has no value!

With kind regards Marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a dataset that has a query that you defined? If so you could base your query on the filter input.  So for instance you could add a parameter to your Report Builder Report that passes in a value to your query (All, ,NotMissingOrder).

So the below takes in a param passed in from the report "@FilterParam" which as a value of NotMissingOrder if the filter is selected.  This would exclude those records where Order doesn't have a value from the output.  You could set the default value of the param to = 'All' So that otherwise everything would be returned:

```
Select *
From Table t
Where(isnull(t.Order,'MissingOrder') = @FilterParam
      Or 
      @FilterParam = 'All')
```

Comment: Why you triyng to do it in the report builder ? in the SQL management studio, you can simply run the followsin query: `SELECT name, order, weight, temp FROM yourTable WHERE order is null`